# Update con Inner Join 2 tablas - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join, update

Necesito actualizar en oracle la tabla `DEPARTAMENTO`, asignarle el jefe que tenga el mayor sueldo;

```
TABLA DEPARTAMENTO:
-----------------------------
DEPTO_ID | JEFE_ID | NOMBRE |
----------------------------

TABLA EMPLEADO:
-----------------------------------
EMP_ID| DEPTO_ID| NOMBRE | SUELDO |
----------------------------------
```

Así es como saco el mayor empleado con sueldo por departamento:

```
SELECT  DEPTO_ID , MAX(SUELDO) FROM EMPLEADO GROUP BY DEPTO_ID
```

pero, no sé cómo hacer un update que dependa de otra tabla.

cada departamento debe quedar en el campo "`JEFE_ID`" con el id (`EMP_ID`) del empleado con **Mayor SUELDO** para ese departamento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te habías quedado a un par de pasos de la solución:

- Localizar qué empleados cobraban ese sueldo máximo por departamento (el que ya habías localizado) y
- Vincular ese resultado con la tabla `DEPARTAMENTO` para poder realizar el `UPDATE`

> ```
> UPDATE DEPARTAMENTO JOIN (
>     SELECT DEPTO_ID,EMP_ID FROM (
>         SELECT  DEPTO_ID , MAX(SUELDO) AS SUELDO
>           FROM EMPLEADO GROUP BY DEPTO_ID
>       )  C0 JOIN EMPLEADO
>       ON C0.DEPTO_ID=EMPLEADO.DEPTO_ID
>       AND C0.SUELDO=EMPLEADO.SUELDO    
>   ) AS c1 ON DEPARTAMENTO.DEPTO_ID=c1.DEPTO_ID
>   set JEFE_ID=EMP_ID;
> ```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó!